# Software that easily allows to do a split screen video from 2 videos

Tags: video, video-editing

I'm searching for some (preferabibly free) software that allows to easily do that.

I mean it should be something like choosing "merge" option, then to be able to select "video1" and then "video2", press a button like "Merge selected videos", and a new video is created with each video displaying on half of the screen.

The final result would be something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pk9ouMC7qE0

Although, in my case, I wouldn't even need to sync videos.

Can you, please, recommend me one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No GUI but you can do this, and more, from a [python](https://www.python.org/) or [ipython](https://ipython.org/) interactive shell with [MoviePy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/) by using a [clip_array](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/getting_started/compositing.html#stacking-and-concatenating-clips). *Note that MoviePy uses [FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org/) behind the scenes but if necessary downloads its own copy automatically on first use.*

Installation:

1. Install Python3 if you don't have it already
2. run: pip install ipython moviepy

An example *(note that you will get both audio streams at once with this code)*, from within Python or iPython:

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, clips_array
clip1 = VideoFileClip("my_first_video.mp4") # Optionally add a margin with .margin(10)
clip2 = VideoFileClip("my_other_video.mp4")
final_clip = clips_array([[clip1, clip2])
# final_clip.resize(width=480).write_videofile("my_split.mp4") # Resized
final_clip.write_videofile("my_split.mp4") # Width will be combined width
# Go and do something while this last line runs
```

Of course if you need to do this often then you can put it into a python script file that takes the names for the input files and the desired output file.

- Free, Open Source & Gratis
- Cross Platform

Answer (score 1):

I personally use Adobe Premier Rush and I love it.  I have used Final Cut Pro and Adobe Premier in the past but for the price they're not worth it for creating simple split-screen videos.  Here is a Youtube video of how to actually make one:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yc3Un8WacK4

It isn't free, but you can start by paying monthly for it on Adobe and then go to cancel it and they will offer you a much better deal (like 50% off).  You can even try to cancel again later and they usually offer another discount.